# How to exclude one of the variants of com.google.guava dependency while building Gradle projects

Tags: java, gradle, guava, intellij-14, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have included the below dependency in the build.gradle file of my gradle project to work with VertexAi LLM Libraries.

```
implementation group: 'dev.langchain4j', name: 'langchain4j-vertex-ai', version: '0.22.0'
```

I am facing a problem while testing the main function.

The Idea IntelliJ prompt says that it is unable to choose between two variants of com.google.guava:guava:32.1.2-jre (which is a dependency for the VertexAi dependency)

I got the following error message

```
The consumer was configured to find an API of a library compatible with Java 11, preferably in the form of class files, and its dependencies declared externally.

However we cannot choose between the following variants of com.google.guava:guava:32.1.2-jre
      - androidApiElements
      - jreApiElements
```

I think I need to use the jreApiElements variant since I am dealing only with a web application. It looks like the IDE is confused because both variants provided the same number of parameters.

```
All of them match the consumer attributes:
  - Variant 'androidApiElements' capabilities com.google.collections:google-collections:32.1.2-jre and com.google.guava:guava:32.1.2-jre declares an API of a library compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
      - Unmatched attributes:
          - Provides attribute 'org.gradle.jvm.environment' with value 'android' but the consumer didn't ask for it
          - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
  - Variant 'jreApiElements' capabilities com.google.collections:google-collections:32.1.2-jre and com.google.guava:guava:32.1.2-jre declares an API of a library compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
      - Unmatched attributes:
          - Provides attribute 'org.gradle.jvm.environment' with value 'standard-jvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
          - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
```

Please let me know how to choose the jreApiElements variant while excluding the androidApiElements variant. Preferable to do it in build.gradle/project gradle settings since I want the code to be portable.

I have tried the below solutions:

1. Setting the right gradle version in the gradle wrapper properties
   file
2. Adding the parameter applicationDefaultJvmArgs =
   ["-org.gradle.jvm.environment=standard-jvm"] to build.gradle file
   (This made the build fail so I removed it)
3. Adding the below 2 dependencies in build.gradle

   implementation group: 'com.google.cloud', name: 'google-cloud-aiplatform', version: '3.24.0'

   implementation group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '32.1.2-jre'

None of the above solutions worked. Please let me know how can exclude the the android variant of the guava dependency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommendation that we've gotten from some Gradle experts is listed in [our release notes](https://github.com/google/guava/releases/tag/v32.1.0). (I should really mention it in our home page, sorry.)

```
sourceSets.all {
  configurations.getByName(runtimeClasspathConfigurationName) {
    attributes.attribute(Attribute.of("org.gradle.jvm.environment", String), "standard-jvm")
  }
  configurations.getByName(compileClasspathConfigurationName) {
    attributes.attribute(Attribute.of("org.gradle.jvm.environment", String), "standard-jvm")
  }
}
```

We're also told that upgrading from Gradle 6 to Gradle 7 may eliminate the need for that.

That said, we've heard of a few different but related problems. So if this doesn't help in your case, someone may be able to provide another possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

I came across https://github.com/google/guava/issues/6612#issuecomment-1618157335 that worked for me:

```
buildscript {
    configurations.classpath {
        attributes.attribute(Attribute.of("org.gradle.jvm.environment", String), "standard-jvm")
    }
}
```

I was upgrading an old Gradle project from v4 to v8, and I got caught with this problem at v6.